# Проблема с локальным репозиторием maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

> Failure to find com.sdicons.jsontools:jsontools:pom:1.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Данная ошибка появляется, когда запускаю сборку maven.

Я чистил все локальные репозитории, переустанавливал начисто IDE - не помогло.

**com.sdicons.jsontools:jsontools:**  -  в локальном репозитории создается каталог **jsontools** рядом с каталогом **jsontools-core**

**jsontools**  - пустой

**jsontools-core** - здесь лежит скачанный **jsontools-core.1.1.jar**

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sdicons.jsontools</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsontools-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

для версии **1.7** - таких ошибок нет !!!!

Но в этой версии нет **import com.sdicons.json.parser.impl.JSONParser;**, а проект старый и на него нет описания почти.
 Поэтому нужна только старая библиотека.

Все остальные зависимости ( а их много в многомодульном проекте) нормально импортируются.

прокси сервера у нас нет.

Что можно сделать, чтобы исправить это ?

Comment: А вы точно чистили локальный репозиторий maven? Загляните в каталог `home/.m2` - он должен лежать там.

Comment: он пустой, так как репозиторий перенесен в другое место, куда IDE и складывает все зависимости и кроме того, его по указанному вами пути - нет

Comment: Попробуйте использовать внешний maven тогда, а не встроенный

Comment: так я же его и указываю в настройках IDE, я всегда использую только проверенный maven, и указываю в настройках путь к его домашней директории и к его конфигурационному файлу.

Comment: Попробуйте в `Preferences->Maven->Repositories` нажать `update` - ручное обновление локального репозитория

Comment: там не отписано ни одного репозитория, в IDEA 2017 у меня был указан путь к репозиториям MAVEN из сети. На текущий момент нет. У меня IDEA 2019.2. Он должен автоматически быть там создан я не могу создать вручную

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в центральном репозитории. Файл `pom.xml` самого jsontools-core версий 1.1 и 1.2 является дочерним просто jsontools, которого в центральном репозитории сейчас действительно нет.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sdicons.jsontools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsontools</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </parent>
```

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sdicons.jsontools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsontools</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </parent>
```

Правильным решением проблемы будет, если вы свяжитесь с автором jsontools и попросите его исправить это в центральном репозитории.

Временным решением будет создание следующего `pom.xml` файла с последующим однократным запуском `mvn install` в директории, где он находится. Это создаст корректный артифакт `com.sdicons.jsontools:jsontools:1.1` в вашем локальном репозитории.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sdicons.jsontools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsontools</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Java JSON tools</name>
    <description>
        Java JSON Tools, global project. It consists of the core which is relatively independent on
        third party jars and optional parts which might introduce transitive dependencies.
    </description>

</project>
```

Воссоздан по резервной копии https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/jsontools-svn/blob/3a5c8df7b189e4236bf34c4f4b53a4bd49fd91f3/trunk/pom.xml К сожалению оригинальный SVN репозиторий http://svn.berlios.de/jsontools/ с этой версией файла уже недоступен.

Автор jsontools на GitHub https://github.com/branscha/

Comment: Я сделал его отдельным модулем в многомодульном проекте и создал pom.xml. Сборка проходит хорошо.